# Query user roles in loopbacks angular sdk

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to get all roles applied to one user using strongloops angular sdk.

I got it worked with the GET  request `/users/{id}/roles` in my strongloop explorer and it works very well. But I can't figure out how to trigger this request in the angular SDK. I created the `lb-services.js` file and I it has a prototyped function what seems to intended for exactly this request.

```
    "prototype$__get__roles": {
      isArray: true,
      url: urlBase + "/users/:id/roles",
      method: "GET"
    },
```

However I havn't found how to use this function in controller.

Update: it's working calling:

```
User.prototype$__get__roles({id:"1"});
```

but isn't it according to [this](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-angular/issues/26) supposed to called like `getRoles()` ?

Comment: I figured already out how to get it using include filters but I guess that is not the way it meant to be...

Comment: found further discussion to this issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/PWB4naSgYZg

Comment: Yeah, I've same issue. No luck so far :(